# 302 Redirect in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to temporarily redirect all product pages on my domain to my Etsy shop home page. The code I'm using does redirect, however, it picks up the product title and appends it to the Etsy url.

```
Redirect 302 /product http://etsy.wileyvalentine.com
```

Sample URL of a page to redirect:
http://www.wileyvalentine.com/product/apothecary-inspired-marriage-certificate/

Destination page for all:
http://etsy.wileyvalentine.com

Any advice on how to get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The comment above led me in the right path to get to the following code which fixed my problem:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /product http://wileyvalentine.etsy.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

> ```
> # TEMPORARY PAGE REDIRECT
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine on
> RedirectMatch 302 ^/yourpage/?$ http://yourwebsite.com/samplepage/ 
> </IfModule>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect directive matches the full url path, to match against a specific part of the url path , use RedirectMatch

```
 RedirectMatch 302 ^/product/?$ http://etsy.wileyvalentine.com
```

Comment: The RedirectMatch was the way to go (thanks!) but I had to edit your answer for it to work. Final working code was: RedirectMatch 302 /product http://wileyvalentine.etsy.com (had to omit the characters before/after product url)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit my answer. The correct Redirect is :

`RedirectMatch 302 ^/product/apothecary-inspired-marriage-certificate/?$ http://wileyvalentine.etsy.com/`